# Return distinct values dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a class with this structure:

```
public class BusinessObject
{
    public int Column5 { get; set; }
    public int Column6 { get; set; }
    public string Column7 { get; set; }
    public int Column8 { get; set; }   
}
```

and I have this line using LINQ:

```
List<int> test = (from x in BusinessObjectCollection select x.Column5).Distinct().ToList();
```

now this works nice.. but what if I don't know the property that the user wants the distinct values? What if all I have is a string variable that tells me which Column they want the distinct values from???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
List<object> test = (from x in BusinessObjectCollection select x.GetType().GetProperty ("thePropertyName").GetGetMethod().Invoke(x,null)).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `if`. Why complicate this?

Answer (score 0):

Try somethign like this ***pseudeocode!*** :

```
 IQueryable<BusinessObject> filteredBoList = boList.AsQueryable();
 Type boType= typeof(BusinessObject);
 foreach(string filter in filterColumnNames) {
    var found = filteredBoList.Where(p =>    (string)boType.InvokeMember(filter.FieldName,BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, p, null) == filter ).Distinct();
 }
```

**Should** work.

Regards.